# Using generics to simplify lots of very similar methods

Tags: c#, generics

I have a number of classes (more than 40), each one has a number of fields (generally Strings or lists). I then have around 8-10 functions that work on each class (however the functions are not part of the relevant class...), each function is next to identical apart from the field name it works on. So:

```
public static class CMix{

    private static List<CType1> gListType1;
    private static List<CType2> gListType2;

    //...

    public static Tuple<bool, String> FetchType1F1(int aIndex){
        //Bounds checking + return item from gListType1.
    }

    public static Tuple<boo, String> FetchType1F2(int aIndex){
        //Bounds checking + return item from gListType1.
    }

    //...

    public static Tuple<bool, ulong> FetchType2AB2(int aIndex){
        //Bounds checking + return item from gListType2.
    }

}

public class CType1{
    public String mF1;
    public String mF2;
    public ulong mF3;
}

public class CType2{
    public String mAB1;
    public ulong mAB2;
}
```

The above code suggests that the methods are simply get/set methods, they are a little more involved than that, although for brevity I've missed this out. This is also the reason why the methods are not part of the matching classes (i.e. FetchType1F1 in class CType1).

What is bothering me is that the contents of each method is next to identical apart from the fields and List that is worked on. I think I may be able to use generics to create a couple of basic methods, but I'm then struggling on how to reference the correct fields:

```
public static String FetchGenericString <ListType> (List<ListType> aList, int aIndex) {
    //For now return empty string.
    return "";
}

public static Tuple<bool, String> FetchType1F1(int aIndex){
    String mResult=FetchGenericString(gListType1, 0);
}
```

I'm unsure how I can pass a field name to FetchGenericString so that I could call it:

```
String mResult=FetchGenericString(gListType1, 0, mF1);
```

This may not even be the best solution to the problem, so I'll listen to any suggestions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your method to include an accessor for which property you want to find:

```
  public static TValue FetchValue<TList, TValue>(List<TList> aList, int aIndex, Func<TList, TValue> valueSelector)
    {
        return valueSelector(aList[aIndex]);
    }
```

then call

```
String mResult=FetchGenericString(gListType1, 0, a => a.mF1);
```

Have to add though, those prefixes to variable names do not make reading your code very easy. You should consider removing them.

Comment: Thank you very much. :) As for the prefixes, it's a habit I picked up many years ago, and it seems to have stuck... ;)